# error trying to connect to cleardb

Tags: heroku, cleardb

Hi again i want to connect to cleardb instance in heroku i take hostname and credentials from heroku config vars in **CLEAR_DATABASE_URL** but i am getting the following error

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'us-cdbr-east-06.cleardb.net' (111)

im trying to connect in this way

> mysql -u username -p -h us-cdbr-east-06.cleardb.net

any idea why i am getting 111 error?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Error fixed thanks the help from cleardb support team, here support answer

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. You may want to check with your local network
>   administrator and/or ISP to ensure that you are allowed to access
>   remote resources that run on TCP 3306. It is possible that this port
>   has been blocked from your local network and/or machine. To be clear,
>   we performed a connection test on this database and found that it is
>   operating normally, so the next diagnostic step is to check your local
>   connectivity to remote MySQL databases.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> member team