# Cannot connect to clearDB [heroku]

Tags: heroku, cleardb

till last week, I cannot connect to cleardb. The configuration did not changed.
Usually, I connect to my db with this command:

```
 mysql --host=eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com --user=ba2*******61 --password=9*****f heroku_2*********f
```

This is the output I get:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com' (60)
```

However, my configuration might have changed. If yes, how do I get the new configuration?

NB:

```
heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL

CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://b*******1:9****f@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com/heroku_2*******f?reconnect=true
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. One week ago it worked, now is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You may want to check with your local network administrator and/or ISP to ensure that you are allowed to access remote resources that run on TCP 3306. It is possible that this port has been blocked from your local network and/or machine. To be clear, we performed a connection test on this database and found that it is operating normally, so the next diagnostic step is to check your local connectivity to remote MySQL databases.

Reference: [error trying to connect to cleardb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520404/error-trying-to-connect-to-cleardb)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the ops manager for ClearDB. Your issue may be account-based rather than mysql. I'd encourage you to open a Support ticket in our system so we can check that possibility.