# Can't seem to connect to remote database on Microsoft Azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I am following this tutorial to try and connect to my remote database on Microsoft Azure.

I am trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2015/09/16/creating-a-php-web-site-with-a-cleardb-mysql-database-all-with-a-free-azure-student-account/).

The code is reproduces below for ease of access:

```
$sUsername = '*****';
$sPassword = '*****';
$sHost = 'eu-cdbr-azure-west-d.cloudapp.net';
$sDb = 'database';


    try {
          $oConn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$sHost.';dbname='.$sDb, $sUsername, $sPassword);
          $oConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          echo 'Sucess!';


        } catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'eu-cdbr-azure-west-d.cloudapp.net' (110)' in db-connector.php:46
Stack trace:
#0 db-connector.php(46): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=eu-c...', 'bfb1d94b7476ad', 'bf430620')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/maltawed/public_html/library/db-connector.php on line 46`
```

Comment: duplicate of yours ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38343168 ... nevermind, it seems you connected last nite. Maybe you are just new to all of this. Probably little we can do.

Comment: Yeah it is. I'm still learning on my own so its all trial and error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dose your test script on Azure Web Apps environment or you tested your code on local?

If you are testing on local, you can check:

> You may want to check with your local network administrator and/or ISP to ensure that you are allowed to access remote resources that run on TCP 3306. It is possible that this port has been blocked from your local network and/or machine. To be clear, we performed a connection test on this database and found that it is operating normally, so the next diagnostic step is to check your local connectivity to remote MySQL databases.

According the issue [error trying to connect to cleardb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520404/error-trying-to-connect-to-cleardb).

Otherwise, as MySQL server on Azure is provided by ClearDB, you can contact to the ClearDB support team at https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/support for detailed analyze about your clearDB database.

Comment: All I had to do was ask my host to `to allow outgoing connections to port 3306`